# How to convert interval to timestamp with time zone with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, postgresql-9.2

I want to perform this simple query :

```
SELECT
    pid,
    MIN(interval '5 minutes' - current_timestamp - state_change)
FROM
    pg_stat_activity
AND
    current_timestamp - state_change <= interval '5 minutes'
GROUP BY 
    pid
ORDER BY
    2 ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

But PG complains that there is no operator between `interval` and `timestamp with time zone`.

How can I convert my interval to timestamp ?

Comment: Well what do you expect to be the result from "5 Minutes minus a timestamp"? The other way round it makes sense: "a timestamp minus 5 minutes". So I guess you want: `MIN(current_timestamp - state_change - interval '5' minutes)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The impossible conversion is not the problem, it's a matter of evaluation order. Without changing the order of arguments you may write it with parentheses:

```
interval '5 minutes' - (current_timestamp - state_change)
```

and it would work since `interval` - `interval` is supported. Without the parentheses it doesn't work since `interval` - `timestamp` would be evaluated first and it's not implemented.

As a sidenote, since `pid` is unique in `pg_stat_activity`, the `GROUP BY pid` and `MIN` should be suppressed, as in:

```
SELECT
    pid,
    interval '5 minutes' - (current_timestamp - state_change)
FROM
    pg_stat_activity
WHERE
    current_timestamp - state_change <= interval '5 minutes'
```

Comment: I need `MIN` because I'm looking for the lowest difference.

Comment: @Alex: my point was that there's only one `state_change` per `pid`, so grouping by pid and applying `min()` is asking for the minimum in a list of one value, and that just equals this value.